# Set DNS settings Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, dns, settings

Is there a way to change the DNS settings in Ubuntu Touch?
If it's possible, is it possible to use other DNS settings when connected via 3G than the settings used when connected via WIFI?
I cannot find anything in the system settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add your DNS to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`, editing "head" file or adding "tail" file with your dns.

To do this you need write permissions to `/`. You can use `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`.

You can use terminal emulator (download from store) or ssh access to do this.